# How to set icon in caption of image in TrayIcon in Mac, Java

Tags: java, trayicon

I have created a sample java application for using tray icon.

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an error message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);
```

If I use the above then It uses error icon of the system default in case of Linux and Windows but in Mac the look and feel is different. I want to set image for the caption. instead of `TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR` also I do not want to change the icon of tray also. So how to set icon will be displayed in the caption of the message.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: The system tray/tray icon in Java 6 doesn't seem to be very friendly under OSX. I ended up using conditional statements to display a different tray icon and simply pop up a dialog window instead of trayIcon.displayMessage under OSX.

I haven't tried the SWT system tray though, which something you could try.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Sahoo: have you got any solution? please share here. because i am having the same issue on OSX. Thanks